# Weighted sum of last N numbers

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, online-algorithms

Suppose we're receiving numbers in a stream. After each number is received, a weighted sum of the last $N$ numbers needs to be calculated, where the weights are always the same, but arbitrary.

How efficiently can this done if we are allowed to keep a data structure to help with the computation? Can we do any better than $\Theta(N)$, i.e. recomputing the sum each time a number is received?

For example:
Suppose the weights are $W= \langle w_1, w_2, w_3, w_4\rangle$. At one point we have the list of last $N$ numbers $L_1= \langle a, b, c, d \rangle>$, and the weighted sum $S_1=w_1*a+w_2*b+w_3*c+w_4*d$.

When another number, $e$, is received, we update the list to get $L_2= \langle b,c,d,e\rangle$ and we need to compute $S_2=w_1*b+w_2*c+w_3*d+w_4*e$.

**Consideration using FFT**
A special case of this problem appears to be solvable efficiently by employing the Fast Fourier Transform. Here, we compute the weighed sums $S$ in multiples of $N$. In other words, we receive $N$ numbers and only then can we compute the corresponding $N$ weighed sums. To do this, we need $N-1$ past numbers (for which sums have already been computed), and $N$ new numbers, in total $2N-1$ numbers.

If this vector of input numbers and the weight vector $W$ define the coefficients of the polynomials $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$, with coefficients in $Q$ reversed, we see that the product $P(x)\times Q(x)$ is a polynomial whose coefficients in front of $x^{N-1}$ up to $x^{2N-2}$ are exactly the weighted sums we seek. These can be computed using FFT in $\Theta(N*\log (N))$ time, which gives us an average of $Θ(\log (N))$ time per input number.

This is however not a solution the the problem as stated, because it is required that the weighted sum is computed efficiently *each* time a new number is received - we cannot delay the computation.

Comment: Note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) here.

Comment: Are the inputs coming from some known distribution? Do they have any useful mathematical properties? If they do not, then its unlikely that this is possible (unless someone is able to find a neat closed form that is sublinear computable -- I certainly cannot find one). 

Also, are approximations OK? That might be one way to go if its useful to you at all.

Comment: [FIR filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIR_filter) do this, so their design will be relevant.

Comment: @RDN I posed this question as a curiosity, I don't have a practical application in mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an elaboration of your approach. Every $m$ iterations, we use the FFT algorithm to compute $m$ values of the convolution in time $O(n\log n)$, assuming that the subsequent $m$ values are zero. In other words, we are computing
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} w_i a_{t-i+k}, \quad 0 \leq k \leq m-1,
$$
where $w_i$ are the $n$ weights (or the reverse weights), $a_i$ is the input sequence, $t$ is the current time, and $a_{t'} = 0$ for $t' > t$.

For each of the following $m$ iterations, we are able to calculate the required convolution in time $O(m)$ (the $i$th iteration needs time $O(i)$). So the amortized time is $O(m) + O(n\log n/m)$. This is minimized by choosing $m = \sqrt{n\log n}$, which gives an amortized running time of $O(\sqrt{n\log n})$.

We can improve this to worst-case running time of $O(\sqrt{n\log n})$ by breaking the computation into parts. Fix $m$, and define
$$ b_{T,p,o} = \sum_{i=0}^{m-1} w_{pm+i} a_{Tm-i+o}, \quad C_{T,p} = b_{T,p,0}, \ldots, b_{T,p,m-1}. $$
Each $C_{T,p}$ depends only on $2m$ inputs, so it can be computed in time $O(m\log m)$. Also, given $C_{\lfloor t/m \rfloor-p,p}$ for $0 \leq p \leq n/m-1$, we can compute the convolution in time $O(n/m + m)$. The plan therefore is to maintain the list
$$ C_{\lfloor t/m \rfloor-p,p}, \quad 0 \leq p \leq n/m-1. $$
For each period of $m$ inputs, we need to update $n/m$ of these. Each update takes time $O(m\log m)$, so if we spread these updates evenly, each input will take up work $O((n/m^2) m\log m) = O((n/m) \log m)$. Together with computing the convolution itself, the time complexity per input is $O((n/m)\log m + m)$. Choosing $m = \sqrt{n\log n}$ as before, this gives $O(\sqrt{n\log n})$.

Comment: Wonderful solution, thanks, I wasn't really sure if it can be done.

Comment: And it works! C implementation: http://ideone.com/opuoMj

Comment: Meh, I was missing that last bit of code which actually makes it break up the computation, fixed here http://ideone.com/GRXMAZ .

Comment: On my machine this algorithm begins to be faster than the simple algorithm at around 17000 weights. For small numbers of weights it is slow. Benchmark: http://ideone.com/b7erxu

Comment: Very impressive that you actually implemented this! You probably want to optimize over $m$. The choice $m = \sqrt{n\log n}$ is just a rough guide, and might not be optimal. Did you try running the algorithm with different values of $m$?